# How to lookup IP address and port from domain name redirect

Tags: php, dns

I have got a PHP based webpage which is pulling the now playing info from a shoutcast server and displaying it to my end users. This is using the server IP address and port.

Our shoutcast host reserves the right to change our server at any time, and so officially only gives us a domain name to connect to, eg 123.myshoutcastexample.com which then http redirects to the lattest IP address and port number.

Can anyone one let me how to find the destination IP and PORT for any given subdomain using PHP? (assuming it's possible).

Many thanks in advance, Phil.

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php

Comment: @nomistic Why not posting an answer?

Comment: @hek2mgl someone else did below

Comment: Thanks Nomistic, your method sorted it. Cheers, Phil.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how a Shoutcast server would do its redirects, but assuming it uses standard HTTP redirects the `get_headers()` function can be used to get the info:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';

print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
```

This results in the following being displayed (for me):

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 302 Found
    [Cache-Control] => Array
        (
            [0] => private
            [1] => private, max-age=0
        )

    [Content-Type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [1] => text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
        )

    [Location] => http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Jtl-Vd3cOvrj8weB5KRY
    [Content-Length] => 259

    [1] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 ...
)
```

The top level elements of the array with numeric keys (`[0]` and `[1]`) are the HTTP status codes (the first is a 302 redirect got from the original URL, the second is the successful request to the redirect URL). The final destination can be found in the `[Location]` element - in this case the redirect was to `http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Jtl-Vd3cOvrj8weB5KRY`.